# How to set this label using enumitem?

Tags: graphics, enumerate, enumitem

I want to make a label for enumerate that looks like this :

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newlength{\exnormal}
\settoheight{\exnormal}{\scshape x}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item[\bfseries(\resizebox{!}{\exnormal}{1})] First item
  \item[\bfseries(\resizebox{!}{\exnormal}{2})] Second item
  \item[\bfseries(\resizebox{!}{\exnormal}{3})] Third item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Obviously putting `label = \bfseries(\resizebox{!}{\exnormal}{\arabic*})` didn't work.

Comment: Are you trying to emulate lining numerals?

Comment: @AlanMunn I just think a small numeral looks better. (I actually don't even know what lining numerals are.) Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of `label` is a moving argument, so fragile commands need to be protected using `\protect` (warning p. 4 of the `enumitem` manual).  Of course this warning isn't helpful if you don't know what it means. :) See [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/2693) for some explanation.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newlength{\exnormal}
\settoheight{\exnormal}{\scshape x}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\bfseries(\protect\resizebox{!}{\exnormal}{\arabic*})}]
  \item First item
  \item Second item
  \item Third item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you'd be interested in  enumerating with oldstyle numbers, which is easy with `enumitem` alone:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{enumitem,textcomp}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label =(\oldstylenums{\arabic*}), font=\bfseries]
  \item First item
  \item Second item
  \item Third item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]